# Error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'void' to 'double'

Tags: c#, return-type

The compiler gives an error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'void' to 'double'. Help me please.
The code here:

```
static public double Decode(string a)
{
    double c=double.Parse(a);
    return (double)Console.WriteLine(c%3);
}
```

Comment: Console.Writeline doesnt have a return value.

Comment: As the compiler is trying to tell you, your code makes no sense.  What do you think you're returning?

Comment: is variable "a" empty?, and you dont need to cast as double again when you return the value because it is already double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your function and use it like in example below.

```
using System;   
public class Program
{
    public static double Decode(string a)
    {    
        return double.Parse(a);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var decoded = Decode("2.1");

        Console.WriteLine(decoded);
    }           
}
```

> OUTPUT: 2.1

If you want improve this function read about [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine has no return value, so the compiler is telling you this is a mistake.. Its right..

I think what you meant was.

```
static public double Decode(string a)
{
    double c=double.Parse(a);
    Console.WriteLine(c%3);
    return c;
}
```